# HTTPS debugging

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https, openssl

I tried debugging my HTTPS settings for a server and got an error as:

error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain

Here is the complete output of the test.
http://paste.org/pastebin/view/29097

Can anyone comment how can I find more information about it. There are 4 certificates installed on dev.visualwebsiteoptimizer.com, Do i actually need the forth one? Which one of the 4 certificate is self signed certificate, how can I find it and debug and fix it

Thanks

Comment: Not an expert, but check [this link](http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#verify-standard) maybe you will get some more info to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is problem with SSL Installation. It is still showing as SelfSigned Certificate. You can check your SSL Installation at following URL:

https://knowledge.geotrust.com/support/knowledge-base/index?page=content&id=SO9557&actp=LIST

There are other tools are available too:

http://www.redkestrel.co.uk/cgi/decodeCSR.cgi

Please let me know if this would help you wit the same.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to verify that my new chain certificate is working better and is verified.